# What are typical formats of “scholarly work”?

Tags: mathematics, job, faculty-application

Regarding the meaning of scholarly works in a job application I found [What are typical examples of scholarly works?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/138194/what-are-typical-examples-of-scholarly-work)

But I have been confused about the format of this document. Is it just listing my peer-reviewed paper and presentation? I have been asked to provide **up to ten scholarly works and an overview of them** and also "a complete list of publications." I do not know what I shall write exactly.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided additional information about what, exactly, you're trying to do. From the tags in your post, it seems like you're applying for a faculty position in mathematics. Is that correct? If you're applying at the university/college level, "scholarly works" is likely going to refer to your published articles, book chapters, and other peer-reviewed documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a simple list of citations of your scholarly works. In most fields, that's journal articles and books, in others it would also include conference papers. If you have a small list of papers, you could also include poster presentations.

Even if your field typically uses really brief citations, I would suggest something like APA with complete author names.

If possible, people often bold their names in the list of authors, or star their first/shared-first-author papers.

Comment: But they also ask for complete list of publications. What is the difference between them?

Comment: @user40491 I think it's fairly clear - they want 10 of your "best" or most representative works, and then a list of all of them. The former is a subset of the latter.

Comment: Can I put submitted papers in the scholarly works? (For example submitted book chapters and papers)

Comment: @user40491 That's probably field-dependent. Because book chapters are usually requested, that seems fine, but papers I would not include until they are "in revision" or "in publication," since "in submission" is meaningless. I would check with a trusted advisor.

Comment: In math, you're expected to include submitted papers.  They won't count for much, unless your recommenders praise them highly, but they do indicate continued research activity.